# Real time data type issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, casting, real-time, stream-builder, flutter-streambuilder

If I receive real-time data, sometimes the type is List , and sometimes the type is Map<String, dynamic>, and on each type, I want to perform different operations; how can I differentiate them?

Comment: You can check for the instance type at runtime (if (data is List) or if(data is Map<String, dynamic>) but if you were using Firestore and getting real-time data through the stream, it is easy to distinguish because of the type of query (against a collection or against a single document).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function , it return 0--> when given argument is List,1 --> when given argument is Map, 2--> when given argument is no List or Map

```
int  isListOrMap(var d){
  if(d is List){
    return 0;
  }
  if(d is Map){
    return 1;
  }
  return 2;
}
```